# Issue in running django server while pulling code from GIT

Tags: python, django, git, directory, pull

I am working on a project which also contains a got repo initialized in it, we are multiple people working on same project but on different branches,my scenario is one of my friends pushes code to his branch then i pull that code from his branch so now i am having merged code(his and mine) now i push the code to my branch that contains final code.
Now the problem is when i pulled code from his branch then my django server isn't starting, i think there is a directory issue, one more problem is when is witch to project view in pycharm it shows limited files with yellowish background and when i switch to project files it shows all files i am attaching both pictures

**My project directory**

**project View**

[image]

**Project_files_vies**

[image]

Comment: try this ,  python manage.py check and see what is the output for it.

Comment: its saying unable to import models even the directory is correct

Comment: can you pls share the complete traceback

Comment: and inside which folder does manage.py is placed, if you can share your project structure

Comment: `

from contracts.models import cust_contract, contract_charge
  File "/home/brainplow/Desktop/csr/contracts/models.py", line 99, in <module>
    from customer.models import Customer_info
  File "/home/brainplow/Desktop/csr/customer/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from premise.models import PremiseErcotReport
  File "/home/brainplow/Desktop/csr/premise/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from customer.models import Customer_info
ImportError: cannot import name 'Customer_info' from 'customer.models' (/home/brainplow/Desktop/csr/customer/models.py)

`

Comment: i attached hte pictures above in project view its not showing any of my apps and in project_files view its showing all app
Both views contins manage.py

Comment: inside customer app in models.py file is this model is present Customer_info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211380/discussion-between-dark-c0d3r-and-wasif-balol).

Comment: are u available on chat?

Comment: yes i am, @wasif